# Breadcrumb add content type data without any modules

Tags: 7, theming, hooks, bootstrapping

How could I print content type like the breadcrumb, for example

> Home/Content type/Create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using `theme_breadcrumb()`.

Example:

```
/**
 * Implements theme_breadcrumb().
 */
function theme_breadcrumb($variables) {
  // global variable 
  $output = '';
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    $nid = arg(1);
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $output = '<ul class="breadcrumb">';
      $i = 1;
      foreach($breadcrumb as $value) {
        $output .= '<li class="breadcrumb-'.$i.'">'.$value.'</li>';
      $i++;
      }
      if ($node->type == 'content_type') {
        $output .= '<li><a href="' . url() . '" rel="breadcrumb">' .  $node->type . '</a></li>';
      }
    $output .= '<li class="active">'. drupal_get_title() .'</li>';
    $output .= '</ul>'; 
    return $output;
  }
}
```

Comment: @KirshaWeb Thanks for your suggestion... I have done the same concept.